# Why does dijit.form.Select have method setStore() while dijit.form.FilteringSelect doesn't?

Tags: javascript, forms, api, select, dojo

I have a solid background in Java, and after quite some times last year with ExtJS, I'm now facing a new challenge with Dojo. The thing is, I still don't get why there's so much inconsistency in the API.

Why is this method not available for dijit.form.FilteringSelect :

```
setStore(store, selectedValue, fetchArgs)
```

while it's for dijit.form.Select ?

See:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/Select#1_9dijit_form_Select_setStore
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect

Answer (score 1):

The Dojo libraries have "evolved" over time.  Since Dojo is open source, it has been contributed to by many folks just like you and me.  Not everyone followed the same conventions and standards at the start.  Efforts to "polish" Dojo continue and in future releases, there will be more consistency.

Looking at this specific example, we see that the goal is to set the "store" property of the widgets.  I believe the correct way to perform this task is either:

```
var myWidget = new MyWidget({ store: myStore });
```

which would be used during widget construction or else to set it later using:

```
myWidget.set("store", myStore);
```

which is the generic way to set any property in a widget.

Both of the above techniques should work just fine for both Select and FilteringSelect.  The fact that one of the widgets has an additional "non-standard" setter mechanism is likely to have come from history when the developer explicitly added that option.  When the standardization came along, the method could have been removed but the danger there is that any pre-existing applications would stop working and that would be considered worse.  As such, we should really consider the non-standard option as deprecated.  I would have hoped to have seen it documented as deprecated in the API reference (but didn't).

Comment: The thing is the `setStore` method on the `dijit.form.Select` is doing more than just setting the store; it sets the selected value, as well as the fetching arguments. Which help doing just one call instead of three.